# Jquery selector table>row>cell>field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

with this I get all input fields in a table

```
$( "table.form>tbody>tr>td>input" )
```

return:

```
<input id="id_form-0-id" type="hidden" value="21">
<input id="id_form-1-id"  type="text" value="31">
```

now I need to read a value, this code return the value of the first input field in list:

```
$( "table.form>tbody>tr>td>input" ).val();
"21"
```

I've tried:

```
$( "table.form>tbody>tr>td>input" )[1].val();
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

how can I get another field value by is index position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$( "table.form>tbody>tr>td>input" )[1].val();
```

is giving you the *native* javascript `DOM` element.

So either do

```
$( "table.form>tbody>tr>td>input" )[1].value
```

or use jQuery [**:eq()**](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) as a selector like

```
$( "table.form>tbody>tr>td>input:eq(1)" ).val();
```

or [**.eq()**](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) as a method like

```
$( "table.form>tbody>tr>td>input").eq(1).val();
```

Answer (score 1):

I didnt get you question fully but if you want the values of the individual text fields then try this.

```
$( "table.form>tbody>tr>td>input:nth-child(x)" ).val();
```

where x will be the element no whose value you want.And x will start from 1.
So values of 1st element would be

```
$( "table.form>tbody>tr>td>input:nth-child(1)" ).val();
```

and so on...